# Include non existent value to by group in proc sql - SAS

Tags: sas, proc-sql

I have a a question with SAS programming.

For example sashelp.cars, and I want to group them by origin and total their MSRP.

Question is, what if I want to add 'Australia' in the list of by group but in the sashelp.cars, there are no make/model that originated from Australia?

What I did is to use proc sql:

```
proc sql;
   create table sample as
      select *, sum(MSRP) as total_srp
   from sashelp.cars
   group by origin;
quit;
```

But in output dataset sample, I only see 'Asia' 'Europe' and 'USA' since they are the only one's available from sashelp.cars.

Is there a more straightforward way to include Australia in the output dataset sample with 0 total_srp even though it's not existing before the by group?

What I'm thinking is having a meta table with complete list of Origin:  'Asia' 'Europe', 'USA" and "Australia" and then look-up into the sashelp.cars so that it will have a 'dummy' value before doing the proc sql.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do the SQL step first, then merge the result with your meta file of all possible origins that you would like to see in the output.

```
proc sql;
   create table meta (origin char(9));
   insert into meta values('Asia');
   insert into meta values('Australia');
   insert into meta values('Europe');
   insert into meta values('USA');

   create table sample as
      select *
      from meta as m full outer join (
         select *, sum(MSRP) as total_srp
         from sashelp.cars
         group by origin) as s 
      on s.origin = m.origin;


quit;
```

You would probably have to modify the *select* statement (avoid wild cards - this code will reorder the columns, make sure you put *origin* from the *meta* file - or use the [COALESCE](https://documentation.sas.com/?cdcId=pgmsascdc&cdcVersion=9.4_3.5&docsetId=sqlproc&docsetTarget=p1gdr5t7sd3g3qn1d7fg23zuwzml.htm&locale=en) function to put them together from both files, etc.).

You should also think about what kind of [join](https://documentation.sas.com/?cdcId=pgmsascdc&cdcVersion=9.4_3.4&docsetId=casfedsql&docsetTarget=n1jstfybqg5boxn1odnb9gfacszq.htm&locale=en) is appropriate.

Comment: Hi @rwc will check on this. I created a meta dataset using datastep but I will consider this also. Thank you!